# Having an unbalanced mixed effect model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, biostatistics, diversity

Setting the scene: I have 32 samples of biological diversity. Each sample's diversity was calculated from a plot randomly generated in a area (that was defined as an "area" by me). However the problem here is that I didn't have equal number of plots in each area. In some cases I only had one plot in one area.

Question: Should I be running a mixed-effect model where "area" is treated as a random effect (random intercept) when my data has unbalanced nestedness (1 plot in one area, 3 in another area)?

***I tried nesting my sites in areas but didn't have the sample size to even run the model

```
Diversity ~ habitat variables + (sites|area)
```

therefore I figured treating "area" as a random effect itself would be the next step.

```
Diversity ~ habitat variables + (1|Area)
```

What I know: According to Zuur's book (as well as I can understand it) the first stage of a mixed effect model is running OLS regressions within each "Area". However, if you only have one plot (or one sample) in one area then I don't think you can even do that. However the package "lme4" still manages to run the model.

Notes: Interestingly enough, simple linear models show much better AIC scores compared to the mixed models I have tried. Yet both simple linear and mixed effect models explain ~ the same variation with R-squared values close 0.5.
However, the rsquare values I get for the random effects are also as high as 0.5.

Any suggestions or input would be appreciated.